# How to run RUTA script from command line

Tags: uima, ruta

How to run Ruta scripts from command line?
I tried this but not sure if this is right command.
`javac DataExtraction.ruta`

Error : `error: Class names, 'DataExtraction.ruta', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the .java classes, UIMA Ruta scripts cannot be run in command line. You could, however, wrap the Ruta scripts within an UIMA Java annotator and access it in command line through the java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Youc an use the main method of `org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher`, but you need to built to classpath yourself, e.g., uimaj-core, ruta-ep-ide-ui and ruta-core with their dependencies.